# Sort an array of dictionaries with dictionaries, can I use sortUsingDescriptors?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary

I can't figure out how to sort my array. It's an array with dictionaries with dictionaries inside. So to get the startdate I would need to write

```
NSDictionary *object = [array objectAtIndex:0];
[[array objectForKey:@"DATE"]objectForKey:@"startDate"];
```

I want to sort the array, but because I need to sort it accordingly to the second dictionary I cant use this:

```
[array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES]]];
```

I guess I just need to make some small adjustment, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the line that you get your objects should be called on `object` instead of `array`. Furthermore you could use `valueForKeyPath` instead of `objectForKey` for nested dictionaries. Something like this:

```
[object valueForKeyPath:@"DATE.startDate"];
```

Now you just apply the same thing to your sort descriptor:

```
[array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"DATE.startDate" ascending:YES]]];
```

Keep in mind though that `sortUsingDescriptors:ascending:` it's a method that sorts in place and must be called on an `NSMutableArray`. If you just want a sorted copy of your array then use `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` method instead. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I could write it like that. And yeah of course it should be called on object, that was just I typo, sorry about that.